# Trying to add a URL Auto redirect every 120 seconds in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am very new to coding so any help would be appreciated.

I am attempting to gather some basic survey data about video conferencing technology I am testing at work and the paid solution I am using routes to an advertisement page after the survey is completed. Since I won't be able to re-launch the web url every time the survey is taken, I would like for the page to automatically redirect back to the initial URL page every 2 minutes. Below is my existing code.
Thanks.

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {
    var webView: WKWebView!

    override func loadView() {
        webView = WKWebView()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let url = URL(string: "https://Mysurveypage/1234")!
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 120.0, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.toDoTask), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)



func toDoTask() 
 {
    let url = URL(string: "https://Mysurveypage/1234")!
    webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))



 }
```

First time can call `toDoTask()` in `viewDidLoad()`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate{

    var webView = WKWebView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        view = webView
        let url = URL(string: "https://Mysurveypage/1234")!
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        webView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        //Uncomment the following line of code to reload the webview currently on top of navigation stack, or in plain words, current browser tab showing in mobile window, Comment the other timer code if you intend to do this
        //Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2 * 60, target: self, selector: #selector(reloadWebView), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

        // Following line of code reloads the initial url i.e. "https://Mysurveypage/1234"
        Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 2 * 60, target: self, selector: #selector(redirectToInitialUrl), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc private func reloadWebView() {
        webView.reload()
    }

    @objc private func redirectToInitialUrl() {
        let url = URL(string: "https://Mysurveypage/1234")!
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }
}
```

PS: Apple documentation says, [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview):

> You should never call this method directly.

It's usual to do all one time functions/operations, that one wants to do in UIViewController's life-cycle, in viewDidLoad() method.

Comment: The OP wasn't calling `loadView`. There is nothing wrong with the code posted by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for the responses. So unfortunately I am so new to coding, I did not know where to enter Jagdeep's code, but copying naeemjawaid's code worked great. I did have to delete the word "Home" from the class ViewController line. After that, all works great. Thanks again for the assistance.